# monitor the dataflow component performance of SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis

I want to monitor the performance of each component of dataflow of SSIS packages is this possible and how to do it. I have used the SSIS pipeline counters in the monitor performance but it provides the total amount, not in detail.
I am using the SSMS 2016 and Windows server 2016. I cannot install any application on the machine, I do not have access to the code of the SSIS just the SSMS.

Comment: Are you able to view the built-in reports in SQL Server Management Studio, such as the All Executions report or the Integration Services Dashboard?

Comment: @AntoineHernandez yes I can ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you run an SSIS package that exists in the SSISDB, it will run at logging level `Basic` That captures information about the execution at the task level - how long, disposition, etc.

To get component level data, then you're going to need to change the logging level to Performance which will then capture details at the Component level (and Task level). As Koen's article on mssqltips notes, you will lose the summary data Component X wrote YYY rows switching to this but you will gain the statistics you are looking for.

If you're on 2016+, then you can define your own logging levels which would allow you to fine tune the specific data you want your logging level to capture.

Either way, now that you know you want to use a different logging level from the default, when you invoke your SSIS Package (either right click and run or from within a job), you'll need to specify that this package should use Performance/MyCustomLoggingLevel instead of Basic in the resulting GUI.

Reading material

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4773/logging-level-recommendations-for-the-sql-server-integration-services-catalog/
- https://www.mattmasson.com/2011/12/setting-a-default-logging-level-in-the-ssis-catalog/
- https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/12/22/ssis-custom-logging-levels/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-customized-logging-level?view=sql-server-ver15